# ReflectionTypeLoadException on Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable) when upgraded from .Net Framework 3.5

Tags: .net, sqlite, x86, 64-bit

Upgrading from Net Framework 3.5 to 4 or 4.5 or 4.6 , my code hangs on a trivial `Me.Adapter.Fill(dataTable)` statement.
If I run my code on x86 Platform, code hangs without error. If I pause compile procedure I can find it blocked in this statement. But if I run it on x64 Platform stops in same code with a

> ReflectionTypeLoadException occurred
>
> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information

(Break on CLR enabled), but then compiles ok. Also compiles on x64 with visual studio hosting process enabled.
What happened?

Comment: What's the stack trace & LoaderExceptions?

Comment: I can't see it because the messages comes with a ballon which not report it.

Comment: Look in the Locals window when it pauses.

Comment: StackTrace: System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   σε System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()

Comment: Please add the full stack (from the Call Stack window) to your question.

Comment: I found that Loader Exception has nothing to do with adapter.fill: Cannot load file or assembly Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll [...]  HRESULT: 0x800700C1. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113968/discussion-between-anefeletos-and-slaks).